# Determining next row in R

Tags: r

Suppose I have this dataframe, df:

```
 UserID <- c(1, 1, 1, 5, 5)
 PathID <- c(1,2,3,1,2)
 Page <- c("home", "about", "services", "home", "pricing")
 df <- data.frame(UserID, PathID, Page)
```

```
   UserID PathID  Page
1  1      1       home
2  1      2       about
3  1      3       services
4  5      1       home
5  5      2       pricing
```

I would like to know the next Page if Page = home. Not sure how to proceed. Any direction is much appreciated.

Comment: Would this help ? `df$nextPage <- c(df$Page[-1], NA)` then you can subset `subset(df, Page=='home')`

Answer (score 2):

With `which` and +1, you can extract the value after `page == "Home"`.

```r
df$Page[which(df$Page == "home") + 1]
[1] "about"   "pricing"
```

You can also use `dplyr::lead`:

```r
dplyr::lead(df$Page)[df$Page == "home"]
[1] "about"   "pricing"
```

Comment: The `which` version might return `NA` in case there is a hit on the last position.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(pnext = if_else(Page == "home", lead(Page), NA_character_))

#>   UserID PathID     Page   pnext
#> 1      1      1     home   about
#> 2      1      2    about    <NA>
#> 3      1      3 services    <NA>
#> 4      5      1     home pricing
#> 5      5      2  pricing    <NA>
```

---

In case we only need the result as a vector:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(pnext = if_else(Page == "home", lead(Page), NA_character_)) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(pnext)) %>% 
  pull
 
#> [1] "about"   "pricing"
```

Answer (score 1):

In *base* it could be don with:

```
df$Page[c(FALSE, (df$Page == "home")[-nrow(df)])]
#[1] "about"   "pricing"
```